# Tabular Menu On Flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask

im trying to recreate an app from php into flask.
im new in flask so i decided to recreate everything. im currently stuck on this multiple tabular menu like

```
a(active menu)| b(inactive) | c (inactive
              ----------------------------
Item Form
A :
B :
C :
```

on the php app it used this code

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title','New Issue Form')
@section('container')

<div class="ui tabular menu">
  <a class="item" data-tab="tab-1"><i class="plus icon green"></i>New Issue Form</a>
  <a class="item" data-tab="tab-2"><i class="warning circle icon red"></i>In Progress</a>
</div>
<div class="ui tab active" data-tab="tab-1">
<div class="ui container text raised very padded segment">
```

on the flask one i copied and pasted it since i dont know how to properly do it

```
<div class="ui tabular menu">
    <a class="item" data-tab="tab-1"><i class="plus icon green"></i>New Issue Form</a>
    <a class="item" data-tab="tab-2"><i class="warning circle icon red"></i>In Progress</a>
</div>
<div class="ui tab active" data-tab="tab-1">
    <div class="ui container text raised very padded segment">
```

it seemed like a normal html to me but i don't know how to use it in my flask view page since i've tried it and it doesn't seem to work. and it just returned
plain unclickable text [image]

while it was suposed to be like this

[image]

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what the problem was!

Comment: check if css are applied  / style sheet linked properly